# How does gdb use register as address and display offset content?

Tags: printing, gdb, offset, display, operand

In gdb:

> p $ebp #will print content pointed by ebp
>
> p 4$ebp # gdb says this is illegal operand.

I wish to show 4 bytes after the address pointed by ebp, and display an int. How to specify this command in gdb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> p $ebp #will print content pointed by ebp

No, it will print the *value* of `$EBP`.

> I wish to show 4 bytes after the address pointed by ebp, and display an int.

```
(gdb) x/x $EBP+4
(gdb) x/d $EBP+4
(gdb) p *(int*)($EBP+4)
```